# How to format Rails video embed via WYSIWYG Redactor editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, redactor

For my rails application, I am using Redactor Rails rich text editor.  Right now users, can submit content, including pictures and video.  Right now, video embeds are dropped in as the following:

```
<iframe width="600" height="338" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/00000000?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
```

I output this along with other content entered into the text editor like this:

```
<%= raw post.content %>
```

So users can submit various content. But for video embeds, I want to be able to format it via CSS so it resizes correctly to fit the box it is sitting in. My question is, is there a way to format this piece of code by adding a `<div class "format">...</div>` for "if" `<iframe>`?